# Problem with producing triangle wave in python

Tags: python, plot

I would like to plot a triangle wave, that has an amplitude in volts A=1V and frequency 1Hz.

My code is the following :

```
from scipy import signal
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> t = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
>>> plt.plot(t,1* signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 1 * t,0.5))
plt.xlabel("Time[s]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude[V]")
plt.title("Singal for sampling")
```

But the output I get is this:

[image]

Why isn't it a perfect triangle wave like this one? (do I need to change something in my code?

output I want

[image: output I watnt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have figured out the answer , it had something to do with the 3rd parameter of linspace. I made it 300 or 400 and it fixed it. Thanks to all

Answer (score -1):

The snippet below does it:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)
plt.plot(t, signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * t, 0.5))
```

For more **help**, do:

```
>> from scipy import signal
>> help(signal.sawtooth)
```

Comment: Beside removing the two redundant multiplications by 1, how is this code any different from what the OP shows?